How could jet engine spools get connected?
I understand that the design jet engines have two or three spools in order to make every component running within its optimal design. But that's still not clear to me.
So, a bit of confusion still exist here. If you could pls explain how they are connected together?
Are they using coupling?
OR
they extend spools inside each other?
Thank you

In short
A spool holds the spinning compressor (or fan) rotors and the turbine rotors. Each spool is independent of the other(s). Still all spools must have their shafts centered within the engine, i.e. within the stationary vanes and the outer duct, and they must be at a fixed location on the longitudinal axis.
Centering and longitudinal lock are done using two stationary frames fixed to the wing, and bearings. One of the shaft, the N1/low pressure spool is solid, N2 and N3 shafts are hollow, and coaxial to the main shaft, at a distance from N1 determined by bearings. The frames keep all bearings (and the rest of the engine!) at a fixed position relatively to the wing.
The frames are often confused with stator vanes. One of the frames, the fan frame on the left, along with the cage and inner ring of a bearing (frame and bearing are not a the same scale):

Fan frame and shaft bearing. Sources: left, right.
Details
The slower spool shaft (N1) is usually directly supported by the frames through bearings. The other spool shafts are supported by the N1 shaft and other bearings. There are variants, e.g. for a CFM56-7B with two spools:

CFM56-7B architecture, from CFM56-7B familiarization manual.
Bearings are magenta disks (ball bearings) and squares (cylindrical bearings). The green N1 shaft is supported by the two stationary red frames. You can see the blue hollow N2 shaft is coaxial to N1, centered by two more bearings, one with the fan frame, one with N1. This results in this structure:

The pink parts are the two conical ends of the an incompletely shown N2 shaft (blue on the first diagram), the golden shaft is N1 (green on the first diagram).
Cylindrical bearings are used to center the shaft within the frames while ball bearings are used both for centering and to prevent shaft longitudinal motion.
Both spool are spun by their respective turbine on the right side. Each spool spins a compressor (or fan) on the left side. It may be easier to see this in motion on this video:



The specific N1 and N2 rpm are determined by the balance between the different sections of a spool and the different spools. CMFI uses 2 spools, Rolls-Royce uses 3 spools. Each design has pros and cons. RR is able to get the different flows and rpm they want more easily than CFMI, at the price of a more complex shaft design. On the other hand CFMI has to adjust the less than optimal resulting flows and rpm using vanes with a variable angle of attack (VSV), bleed valves, etc, which also add complexity.
More:

How are engines mounted onto wings?, explains how the two frames are fixed to the wing.

In a turbofan what holds the spinning axis?, gives more details about the mechanical design of the spools and the frames.


